# Can't add the `r` tag to "Tech I want to work with" on my jobs page

Tags: bug

I was updating my job page and tried to add the `r` tag to the "tech I want to work with" section. Unfortunately, i wasn't able to as upon searching, the `r` tag didn't appear (as it normally does when added to questions).

Is this a bug or a feature? If the latter, how would I add the `r` tag? I could add `python` and `rstudio` appeared.[image]

---

**EDIT:**

Just tried the suggestion from an answer below to type `r` followed by a space and that should add the tag automatically. Still didn't work. A space after `r` simply erased the `r`. I've added a `.gif` of [what it looked like on my end here.](https://i.imgur.com/ovT10YK.gifv)

**EDIT 2:**

At the risk of looking like a fool, this was a case of **operator error.** Turns out that I had already added the `r` tag but it was higher up the "tag chain" and wasn't visible in the limited window provided. As a result, trying to ad the `r` tag a second time just causes it to disappear. Thank you. And now I'll go back to my technology hole for the weekend.

Comment: Single character search fail.

Comment: What brower are you using?  Also what page are you on?  The place I went to change these settings doesn't resemble your screenshot.

Comment: My box doesn't straight delete even if I type nonsense and press space...

Comment: @ryanyuyu I'm on `stackoverflow.com/users/jobsearch/[userid]`.

Comment: Have you tried `r` followed by a comma?

Comment: Thank you everyone. It was a case of operator error. Today was Friday.

Answer (score 2):

Just tested this myself.

Type 'r' and press space. So long as you don't have a tag in the search highlighted, it should just add the [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r) tag for you. If you click on the tag after it's added, it should show the correct tag for the first result.

Comment: Just tried to do this and still failed. I added a `.gif` of what was going for me in the question.

Comment: What browser and OS are you using? I tried this myself, like I said, before I posted. Are you running any extensions? Scripts?

Comment: **OS** Windows 7 SP1; **broswer** Chrome Version 63.0.3239.132 (Official Build) (64-bit); **Extensions** uBlock Origin

Comment: Try without uBlock? Because otherwise, we have the same setup.

Comment: Thanks. Operator error. Friday.